# Как сделать отправку фото вместе с текстом и кнопками в одном сообщение? библиотека aiogram | python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlalchemy

**Цель:  Отвечать пользователю в одном сообщение: фотографией, текстом, кнопками при этом выводить информацию из базы данных**

**Имеется: Функция, обрабатывающая начальную команду /start.**

*На данный момент в ней подключен только вывод текста и кнопок*

```
async def cmd_menu(msg: types.Message, user: User):
    await msg.answer(
    ' Привет, {}\nВаш скрытый id для решения споров: {}'.format(user.username, user.hidden_id),
    reply_markup=(await get_menu(user, msg.bot)))
```

> Попытки следовать документации привели к провалу, а так же к ряду
> ошибок, получилось сделать вывод фото и кнопок но увы без текста т.к
> записи из базы данных (user.username, user.hidden_id) не отображались.

**Ошибки:**

```
await bot.send_photo(user, types.InputFile('src/bo.png'))
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

await Bot.send_photo(photo=types.InputFile.from_url(URL))
TypeError: send_photo() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'chat_id'

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'parse_mode'

  File "/root/bot/handlers/user/menu.py", line 2068, in cmd_menu
    await Bot.send_photo(msg.from_user.id, MAIN_PHOTO, caption, reply_markup=(await get_menu(user, msg.bot)))
```

**Думаю что проблема в самом методе который я использую.**

Если кто-то знает как делается вывод: фото, текста, кнопок и записей из базы данных буду рад любому предположению

Comment: Cохраняйте в бд не конкретный файл, а message.photo[-1].file_id + отдельно можно в таблице БД держать message.caption - подпись к фото, видео. А зачем для этих манипуляций БД?

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! 
У меня полноценный телеграм бот пользующийся спросом из-за этого бд и нужно. Скорее всего вы неправильно меня поняли, мой вопрос заключается в том, чтобы сделать ответ бота с фотографией, текстом и кнопками. 
reply_markup=await get_menu... Это часть функции, которая вызывается командой /start сделано для того чтобы код вышел не сильно большим

Comment: Если вы можете показать пример кода как это должно выглядеть буду очень благодарен, может это я неправильно понял вас))

Answer (score 1):

Хз, что вы там делаете ибо вы не показали как вы отправляете фото. Но вот рабочий способ.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("text", callback_data="cd"))
    await msg.answer_photo(photo=msg.photo[-1].file_id, caption="caption", reply_markup=markup)
```

Вариант через экземпляр класса бот.

```
bot = Bot(token=...)

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=msg.chat.id, photo=msg.photo[-1].file_id, caption="caption", reply_markup=markup)
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]