# Как получить текст к изображению aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно узнать текст, который написан к изображению в aiogram
[image: пример что мне нужно узнать]

Если в сообщении нету картинки, то `message.text` выдаёт текст.

А, если нет - выдаёт `None`

Как узнать текст?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать отправку фото вместе с текстом и кнопками в одном сообщение? библиотека aiogram | python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393425/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

описание фото называется caption. Попробуйте `message.caption`